# What is meant by "rational operation"?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, operator-theory, rational-functions

So I am attending a course in complex analysis and came across the following statement pretty early in the book:

Let $R(a,b,c,\dots)$ stand for any rational operation applied to the complex numbers $a,b,c,\dots$

Then
$$ \overline{R(a,b,c,\dots)}=R(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c},\dots)$$

Where the bar denotes complex conjugation. [Lars Ahlfors, Complex analysis, 3rd. edition]

What exactly is meant by rational operation?

My first thought was that maby this meant that: 
$$ R(a,b,c,\dots)=\frac{P(a,b,c,\dots)}{Q(a,b,c,\dots)}$$
Where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials of (finite) degree in the varibales $a,b,c,\dots $

If my first interpretation is correct, then surely $P$ and $Q$ must have real coefficients, right?

My second thought was that maby this simply means a sequence of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division applied to $a,b,c,\dots$, with the assumption that no zero-divison takes place.

If not, what is the correct interpretation / meaning of the statement?

Thanx, R :)

Comment: Your second interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ahlfors wrote "Rational **operation** applied..." I think that he means a sequence of sums, subtractions, products and quotients to the given complex numbers.

That will give, simplifying the operations, a rational function, that is an element of the field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x].$

Comment: Yes, the use of the word "operation" is what suggest.

Comment: Yeah, It sounds the most resonalble, doesn't it?  By the way, If I define $$ R_n(a,b,c,\dots) $$ as the operation applied to only the first $n$ complex numbers in $a,b,c, \dots $, then I can easily show that $$\overline{R_n(a,b,c,\dots)}= R_n(\overline{a},\overline{b},\overline{c},\dots)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, given that the sequence of operations converge to some complex number, then I would be able to show that $$\overline{ R(a,b,c,\dots) }= \overline { \lim_{n \to \infty} R_n(a,b,\dots) } =\lim_{n \to \infty} R_n(\overline{a},\dots) =R(\overline{a},\dots)$$ , maby? :)